# Random Samples from Gamma distribution with two parameters / Python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats, gamma-distribution

If I would like to generate 10 random samples from a gamma distribution with (with the following form):

[image]

with alpha = 2 and beta = 3, how would I do it?

The documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html
is a bit unclear to me.

My guess is that it would be like:

```
a = 2 
b = 3 
scipy.stats.gamma.rvs(a, loc = 0, scale = 1/b, size = 10)
```

Can anyone verify wether this is correct or provide the correct solution?

Comment: what bit is unclear?

Comment: How to generate samples when the distribution has the form provided in the question @anon01.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.  In the formula that you show, β is often called the *rate* parameter.  The `gamma` distribution in SciPy uses a *scale* parameter, which corresponds to 1/β.  You can see the formulas for these two common parameterizations side-by-side in the [wikipedia article on the gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

If all you need is the generation of random samples (and not all the other methods provided by `scipy.stats.gamma`), you can use the [`gamma`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.gamma.html#numpy-random-generator-gamma) method of the NumPy class [`numpy.random.Generator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html). It uses the same parameter conventions as the SciPy `gamma` distribution, except that it does not have the `loc` parameter:

```
In [26]: import numpy as np

In [27]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [28]: a = 2

In [29]: b = 3

In [30]: rng.gamma(a, scale=1/b, size=10)
Out[30]: 
array([0.637065  , 0.18436688, 1.36876183, 0.74692619, 0.12608862,
       0.38395668, 0.81947237, 0.63437319, 0.47902819, 0.39094079])
```